# Find the unknown, given three vectors acting on a box and the resultant.

Tags: vectors

I was told that my method for finding $a$ was incorrect. Can somebody point out what I did wrong?

> **Question:** Three Forces $F_1 = 2\mathbf i+3\mathbf j\, \text N$, $F_2 = 5\mathbf i-\mathbf j\, \text N$ and $F_3 = 3\mathbf i+a\mathbf j\, \text N$ act on a box. Resultant force acts in direction $2\mathbf i + \mathbf j$.  Find the value of $a$ and the magnitude of the resultant force.

This is what I did:

$F_r = 10\mathbf i+(2+a)\mathbf j\, \text N$.

$k(2\mathbf i+\mathbf j) = 10\mathbf i+(2+a)\mathbf j$

$2k = 10$, $k = 5$

$5 = 2 + a$

$a = 3$

Comment: I assume that $k$ is your magnitude; then you are calculating it wrong. $k$ should be equal to the norm of $F_r$, that is, $k = \sqrt{2^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{5}$

Comment: I don't think $k$ is the magnitude, it's just a scalar. What ymxzxz is saying is that "for the sum to be in the direction of $2\hat{i}+\hat{j}$, there is a scalar $k$ so that $(10\hat{i}+ (2+a)\hat{j}) = k (2\hat{i} + \hat{j})$". It actually seems all correct to me. $10\hat{i} + 5 \hat{j}$ is very much in the same direction as $2\hat{i}+\hat{j}$.

Comment: @MattiP. Yeah, that's what I was getting at. However, I was told that my method was incorrect, even though the answer was correct. I'm very confused. .-.

Comment: Well, then ask the teacher why the method is wrong and how it should be carried out. I don't see anything wrong with your method. But again, I'm only human ...

Comment: I was told that "you need to figure it out yourself". >.>

Comment: I concur that your approach to finding $a$ seems perfectly reasonable and correct.  Perhaps one might be able to complain that a step or two were glossed over (*such as beginning with $10\vec{i}+(2+a)\vec{j}$ rather than $(2\vec{i}+3\vec{j})+(5\vec{i}-\vec{j})+(3\vec{i}+a\vec{j})$*) but it is clear enough the train of thought and logic used that it shouldn't have been justification to call the method "incorrect."  As alluded to earlier though, the answer is incomplete as you haven't yet found the magnitude of the resulting vector from what I can see.

Comment: The one who is incorrect is whoever told you your method for calculating $a$ is incorrect.